# Why am I getting a closed filehandle error when using the diamond operator in list context in Perl?

Tags: perl, diamond-operator

This code:

```
foreach my $file (@data_files) {

    open my $fh, '<', $file || croak "Could not open file $file!\n";
    my @records = <$fh>;
    close $fh;

    ....

}
```

produces this error:

```
readline() on closed filehandle $fh at nut_init_insert.pl line 29.
```

and I have no idea why.

EDIT:  The original post had ',' instead of '<' in the `open` statement.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have a typo in the code you posted (the second arg to `open`), but that does not explain the error message. The message for that problem would be this:

```
Unknown open() mode ',' at ...
```

Your problem is related to precedence. The `||` binds too tightly, causing Perl to treat this entire expression as the 3rd argument to open:

```
$file || croak $!
```

As a result, even though `open` fails (probably because `$file` is not a valid file name), `croak` is not executed (because `$file` is true and the `||` short-circuits). After the `open` fails, your program tries to read some lines from an unopened file handle, and you get this error message:

```
readline() on closed filehandle $fh at ...
```

You want to use one of the following instead. The second option works (unlike your code) because `or` is low precedence.

```
open(my $fh, '<', $file) || croak ...;

open my $fh, '<', $file or croak ...;
```

For details on operator precedence, see [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Operator-Precedence-and-Associativity). The relevant point in your case is that the `||` operator has higher precedence than the list separator (comma).

Answer (score 1):

There is a typo in 2nd argument to open:

```
open my $fh, '<', $file || croak "Could not open file $file!\n";
```

Comment: Aways create a minimal but complete program and show us the real code. Otherwise, you waste people's time fixing problems you don't actually have.

Comment: The snippet meets your criteria.  Mistakes happen.  FM gave a great answer and I learned something about precedence.  Win-win.